# SQL update only when non null

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE main
SET main.PCH_2YR =
(SELECT TOP 1 sub.PCH_2YR FROM [dbGlobalPricingMatrix].[dbo].[tblPCHLookup_Test] sub WHERE
sub.capid = main.capid AND
sub.milespa = main.mileage AND
sub.maintained = main.maintenance AND sub.pch_2yr IS NOT NULL)
FROM [dbWebsiteLO3-PRICING]..Vehicles_Staging_Data main
```

I only want to set the value if the subquery returns a value that isn't `NULL`. How can I do that?

Only one row will ever match the conditions, but I only want to use it's value if it's not NULL.

Comment: *Don't* put the subquery in the SET clause, put it in FROM and add the proper filter in WHERE. Notice that the `WHERE` of the subquery is essentially a `JOIN` - 3 of the 4 conditions simply join `main` and `sub`. BTW `TOP 1` without an ORDER BY actually means `pick one row at random`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I didn't use ORDER BY as only one row will ever match the conditions, but I only want to use it's value if it's not NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the query like below:

```
UPDATE main
SET main.PCH_2YR =sub.PCH_2YR
FROM [dbWebsiteLO3-PRICING]..Vehicles_Staging_Data main LEFT JOIN
[dbGlobalPricingMatrix].[dbo].[tblPCHLookup_Test] sub ON 
sub.capid = main.capid AND
sub.milespa = main.mileage AND
sub.maintained = main.maintenance AND sub.pch_2yr IS NOT NULL
WHERE sub.PCH_2YR is NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do an `INNER JOIN` on the table instead of sub query. `INNER JOIN`s filter out records that don't have a match in the other table.

```
UPDATE main
SET main.PCH_2YR = sub.PCH_2YR
FROM [dbWebsiteLO3-PRICING]..Vehicles_Staging_Data main
INNER JOIN [dbGlobalPricingMatrix].[dbo].[tblPCHLookup_Test] sub 
        ON sub.capid = main.capid 
        AND sub.milespa = main.mileage 
        AND sub.maintained = main.maintenance 
        AND sub.pch_2yr IS NOT NULL
```